# Using a led driver as a led backlight inverter

Tags: lcd, led-driver

Can i use a led driver to replace an led backlight inverter ?
I have an old MacBook display (LG LP154WP2) and don't really know how to use the inverter board, because i can`t identify the ic on the board. 
Would it be possible to design a new board using a led driver ic like the LM43 line from TI or similar ?
Would there be any problems or are backlight inverters just cheaper led drivers for a specific application ?

Sidenote: Yes i know that there are whole solutions for interfacing laptop displays on ebay, this is more about the learning experience!

Answer (score 1):

For sure,you can use separate LED back-light.All you have to do is to built a circuit with variable PWM(pulse Width Modulation).I think you can implement a PWM varying circuit using an Arduino or with any other micro-controllers.The purpose of the PWM here is to control the brightness of the background LED.

  More or less,nothing else is much complicated in background LED.The background LED is just brighten or dimmed using PWM circuit.